# MYSQL select only selecting characters and not names

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have 2 columns in my database called `description` and `url`
I want to select both of these, but only display the `description` to the user. The problem is, when i iterate through the fetchall command, it either selects both of these or just individual characters. Here's my code:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(user='fake', passwd='fake', host='db', port=1111, db='fake_db_name')
searchResult = []
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        pushpin_sql = "SELECT description, url FROM pushpin WHERE pushpin.description LIKE '%" + str(searchTerm) + "%'"
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        for col in result:
            searchResult+=col
        connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close
```

The output is this:

**this is a cute dog**

**http://jiangzhenling.com/img/CS6400/dog/dog1.png**

if I change it to:

```
        for col1,col2 in result:
            searchResult+=col1
```

Then it only concatenates individual characters

And the output is this:

**t**

**h**

**i**

..and so on. How can I make it only concatenate my description and NOT my url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to the list only the description part of the result. Try this:

```
for col in result:
    searchResult.append(col[0])
```

I leave you the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) with info about the methods of list objects